# How to get elapsed time from a TimeSpan variable to the current time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to persist my timer, I have a list of items in a listview so when a user starts any of the items I want to persist the timer of any of the items. I have a timespan variable that takes in an integer variable total time which is converted to minutes

```
   //Get total time and convert to minutes
   _TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeSheet.TotalTime);
```

How can I get the elapsed time from _TimeSpan variable just like how I would do it with the DateTime.Now, example below uses DateTime.Now to get the elapsed time:

```
            var startAt = DateTime.Now;
            Application.Current.Properties["StartedAt"] = startAt;


            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {

                        TimeSpan _TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - startAt;


                        TxtTimer = _TimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");


                    });

                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Comment: I refer you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0#properties).

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? If you want to measure time, a stopwatch is a good way. A Timespan already represents an elapsed time, so your question does not make all that much sense to me.

Comment: @JonasH I'm trying to persist my timer

Comment: You cannot persist a timer. You can persist a *timestamp* that can be used for timing related things. And there are [many ways to get such timestamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan.Subtract` and then pass your parsed value and current time. You can get current time as `TimeSpan` using `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`.

So the final result should be:

```
var difference = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(_TimeSpan);
```